# Laptop not starting past Dell load screen

Tags: laptop

I attempted to drain the static, which didn't work. Also, I ran the FULL diagnostic, which offered to insight because it said that everything is fine. I really need to fix this, and I don't even know what the problem is right now.

Comment: Not enough information is provided for us to effectively troubleshoot it. What model laptop is this? What did you do immediately before the problem occurred?

Comment: Which OS are You running? I've a dell laptop myself. I'm on Kubuntu and it happens to me from time to time. So when it happens, I have to turn off integrated NIC card in bios and run Kubuntu from a live cd -- just for a minute, and then reboot -- voila -- Kubuntu boots again. After that I turn on NIC in bios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the Dell logo will disappear once the BIOS setup is completed and then the boot process starts.

If this is NOT happening - i.e. it is hanging at the BIOS progress bar, it may be hanging on drive or battery detection.  Remove the battery and see if it that helps.  If not, remove any optical drive, and last, the hard drive.  You won't be able to boot into Windows if you remove the hard drive, of course, but the system should at least tell you "No bootable device found."  If you get down to removing the hard drive and see the "No bootable device found" - try putting the hard drive in another system - if it successfully reads the hard drive, your laptop has a hardware issue, otherwise it's your hard drive.

If the Dell logo goes away and you see one of these:

- a blank screen with a blinking cursor in the upper left
- "BOOTMGR is missing ... "

make sure you've removed any USB drives/SD cards from your system.  If you still get this afterward, your hard drive's bootsector has been knocked out or overwritten for some reason.  You might try running "Repair your computer" from a Windows 7 installer disc.

If you get the message "No bootable device found" - it means it cannot detect the presence of your hard drive, or the drive is not responding on the read command the BIOS uses to boot from the drive.  This usually indicates a hardware failure in the drive - especially if it's not present in the F2 BIOS menu.

If you get to the Windows boot manager menu, where it asks "Launch Startup Repair" or "Start Windows Normally" - try selecting Start Windows Normally. If that does not work, reboot and do the Startup Repair.  If THAT does not work, reboot once more, press F8 at that menu, and select "Last Known Good Configuration."  If that fails, you're looking at a reinstall.

Comment: I'm getting the blinking cursor. I am going to try using the Win7 installer disc, and I will post an update as soon as I have one. By the way, thank you for your extremely detailed answer!

Comment: Aah yes, Windows is back! Now, all I have to do is somehow get my Ubuntu Wubi install back up and running . . . But I think Superuser can help me out with that!